# Print the value of injected parameter in sqlmap

Tags: python, sql-injection, code-injection, sqlmap

I using sqlmap for injection and URL look like 
python sqlmap.py -u "http://localhost/utility/?site_name=30"
so i just want to know what are the values sqlmap try to give input for site_name for injection.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to add -v option and the value of output you want from 1 to 6. in your case is 4

```
python sqlmap.py -u "http://localhost/utility/?site_name=30" -v 4
```

See it
https://github.com/sqlmapproject/sqlmap/wiki/Usage

Answer (score 0):

Sqlmap keeps the log at: 
`**/home/root/.sqlmap/output/**`. root is the user(change user accordingly). 
If you want custom output location you can specify it in `**sqlmap.conf**.` 
If you want everything to be recorded you can do:

```
sqlmap.py -u "http://localhost/utility/?site_name=30" > file_name.txt.
```

Comment: Sorry but I didn't get any list of value that sqlmap pass for injection.

Comment: Do you need the payloads which sqlmap is using 
?